# Dynamically load assemblies in ASP.NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, c#-6.0

I used to have some code which scanned the `bin` directory of my application for assemblies which weren't loaded in the AppDomain yet and loaded them. It basically looked like:

```
foreach (var assemblyPath in Directory.GetFiles("path\to\bin", "*.dll"))
{
    var inspected = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(assemblyPath);
    Assembly.Load(inspected.GetName());
}
```

*I skipped the try/catch clauses, etc for brevity.*

This allowed me to drop assemblies in the bin folder at run-time with implementations for certain interfaces and let the IoC container pick them up automatically. Now with the new Roslyn magic, there are no physical DLL's anymore when debugging. Is there any way to retrieve assembly names, project names or dependency names (in `project.json`) dynamically.

I guess I have to implement something like [this example in the Entropy repo](https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/blob/dev/samples/Runtime.CustomLoader/Program.cs), but I don't know how to implement it for my scenario.

Comment: What o you mean with "there are no physical DLL's anymore"? There's nothing magic about Roslyn that wasn't already being done before ASP.NET5.

Comment: @PauloMorgado the code is now compiled in-memory when debugging. It might still work with a published app, but I want it to work both ways.

Comment: The code has always been compiled in memory. It was just saved to disk and them loaded - different compilers, different APIs. Nevertheless, what was compiled on the website was in one assembly and other assemblies were loaded on demand. What changed?

Comment: @PauloMorgado I'm talking about the assemblies being saved to disk. That allowed me to scan the bin folder and load assemblies dynamically.

Comment: Well, one of us has it all completely wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`ILibraryManager`](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Interfaces/ILibraryManager.cs) implementation which provides access to the complete graph of dependencies for the application. This is already flowed through the ASP.NET 5 DI system. So, you can reach out to it from there.

[Sample usage](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/27191114538c92ac1901bf18cb20124102a99892/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor/Compilation/RoslynCompilationService.cs#L185) can be found inside [`RoslynCompilationService`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/27191114538c92ac1901bf18cb20124102a99892/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor/Compilation/RoslynCompilationService.cs).

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `IAssemblyLoadContextAccessor` interface to load ASP.NET 5 class library (.xproj) projects dynamically. The following example code works with Beta 4:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        var assemblyLoadContextAccessor = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IAssemblyLoadContextAccessor>();
        var loadContext = assemblyLoadContextAccessor.Default;
        var loadedAssembly = loadContext.Load("NameOfYourLibrary");
    }
}
```

Comment: Although this works, the main part of the problem was resolving the assemblies to be loaded dynamically, in stead of hard-coding the `NameOfYourLibrary` as in your example. Nevertheless, for mentioning `IAssemblyLoadContextAccessor`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue partly using the `ILibraryManager` as suggested by @tugberk. I changed the approach a bit which dropped the need of scanning the `bin` folder for new assemblies. I just want all the loaded assemblies in the current AppDomain.

I injected an instance of the `ILibraryManager` interface in my type finder class and used the `GetReferencingLibraries()` method with the name of the core assembly, which is referenced by all the other assemblies in the application.

A sample implementation can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/henkmollema/2e53f59d60833e2bea4f), where this is the important part:

```
public IEnumerable<Assembly> GetLoadedAssemblies()
{
    return _libraryManager.GetReferencingLibraries(_coreAssemblyName.Name)
                          .SelectMany(info => info.Assemblies)
                          .Select(info => Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName(info.Name)));
}
```

Comment: You should avoid loading all assemblies and try to use ILibraryManager in a way that doesn't do that if possible.

Comment: @davidfowl basically the only thing I want is to search for types in the current 'AppDomain'. But since that's not available any more I came up with this approach. Any suggestions?

Comment: Most of the time you don't actually want to look at loaded types. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @davidfowl I'm building a modular application where I need to find a type based on it's full name which is stored in the database. My current approach is looping through all loaded assemblies and their types and look for a match. I also use it to find implementations of (open generic) interfaces.

Comment: Consider the MVC approach to find controllers. MVC looks at all libraries that reference MVC, and then loads only those and checks to see if there are any controllers defined in there.

Comment: @davidfowl I use the `ILibraryManager.GetReferencingLibraries()` to figure out which libraries reference the core library (which all components do) and only 'load' those. But since the assemblies are already loaded (because I use them in the composition root), `Assembly.Load()` won't really load them, will it?

Comment: Beautiful :). That's great! It won't load again, it's cached.

Comment: @davidfowl thanks a lot for your feedback! My implementation basically looks like this: https://gist.github.com/henkmollema/2e53f59d60833e2bea4f.

Comment: @HenkMollema new AssemblyName() just saved my night :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

For .net core users, here is my code for loading assemblies from a specific path.  I had to use directives, as it's slightly different for .Net Framework and .Net Core.

In your class header you'll need to declare the using something similar to:

```
#if NET46
#else
    using System.Runtime.Loader;
#endif
```

And in your function something similar to the following:

```
string assemblyPath = "c:\temp\assmebly.dll";

#if NET46
                Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);
#else
                AssemblyLoadContext context = AssemblyLoadContext.Default;
                Assembly assembly = context.LoadFromAssemblyPath(assemblyPath);
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not ASP.NET but it can be converted easily to asp.net.
bellow if function for loading an assembly, and invoke a method inside a class on that assembly.

```
        private static FormCustomized loadLayout(global::System.String layoutFilename, global::System.String layoutNameSpace)
    {
        FormCustomized mainForm = default;
        Type typeMainLayout = default;
        FileInfo layoutFile;
        layoutFile = new FileInfo(layoutFilename);
        layoutFile.Refresh();
        if (!layoutFile.Exists)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Layout file not found. You need to reinstall the program");
            return default;
        }

        try
        {
            Assembly assemblyRaw = Assembly.LoadFrom(layoutFilename);
            AssemblyLoadContext context = AssemblyLoadContext.Default;
            Assembly assembly = context.LoadFromAssemblyPath(layoutFilename);


            Type typeMainLayoutIni = assembly.GetType(layoutNameSpace + ".initializeLayoutClass");
            Object iniClass = Activator.CreateInstance(typeMainLayoutIni, true);
            MethodInfo methodInfo = typeMainLayoutIni.GetMethod("AssembliesToLoadAtStart");
            enVars.assemblies = (Dictionary<string, Environment.environmentAssembliesClass>)methodInfo.Invoke(iniClass, default);
            typeMainLayout = assembly.GetType(layoutNameSpace + ".mainAppLayoutForm");
            mainForm = Activator.CreateInstance(typeMainLayout, enVars) as FormCustomized;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return default;
        }

        return default;
    }
```