# Loading asp.net 5 assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

For code generation purposes I need to load an asp.net 5 generated assembly via reflection. If it was a normal assembly I would do

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);
```

The problem is that I can't find it's assembly after build.
How can I do something similar in an asp.net 5 assembly from an external process?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the path you're using (relative, absolute, etc.)?  Where is the full path to the assembly?  This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29421029/dynamically-load-assemblies-in-asp-net-5

Comment: Is that path that you pass relative or absolute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After building the ASP.NET 5 project, you should see the assemblies in the `bin/` folder, under the respective target frameworks

For example:

`> dnu build`

should produce

`bin/dnxcore50/MyAssembly.dll`

Comment: thanks, using visual studio I couldn't find the output. using dnu build the assembly gets created. Then I found a new option (I think it's from aspnet 5 rc1) to create assemblies on vs build too. So, problem solved